# PrimeFaces autocomplete multiple style but with Multiple=false

Tags: css, primefaces

How can I get the look and behavior of the autocomplete item selected when using multiple - as in how Afterdark looks in this screen shot with the button look - but only allowing one item (multiple=false) to be chosen?

[image]

Comment: Do you want the look, or the behavior as well (as in, clicking on the x deletes the input?)

Comment: both the look and behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectLimit="1"` is now available in Primefaces Autocomplete